# Want to use index.html from mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

When I loaded up my new website I have some of it using MVC and the other half using static pages.

The first page should be index.html

However when I go to http://domain, it goes directly in to the MVC controller.

It does not go to index.html, even though I have IIS pointing to this page, it might be due to the fact that I am using wild cards from within IIS, as detailed in my blog http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2009/07/02/Deploying-MVC-on-IIS-6.aspx

But I need the first page to go to index.html when I select http://domain

Any ideas?

Comment: See [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6560266/56286 "this solution") provided for a similar question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could direct the path to a controller action and return the file like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File("index.html", "text/html");
}
```

Comment: This causes IE8 to go in to download

Comment: Nope, still getting file download  :-(

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File("index.html", "test/html");
}

working :-)

Answer (score 1):

Tell the routing engine to ignore index.html:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("index.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new RedirectResult("index.html",true);
    }
```

This work for me.