# 403 access denied error occure when i click to an url. I want help regarding this issue

Tags: access-denied

How do i get images from 403 access denied page.
Foe example : http://hhsrv.n.dk/chat/gfx/items/%7BACF45E42-9B9E-426F-89A6-EC5AA54C8802%7D.gif
I need all images from: http://hhsrv.n.dk/chat/gfx/items/

Answer (score 0):

403 generally occurs in the case of permission problem. If you want images to be publically accessible, just give them 755 permissions.

`chmod -R 755 gfx/items/`

Alternatively, if problem persists, check your apache conf for the proper permissions and configuration to this endpoint.

Comment: where to add your given 755 permission in following url :
http://hhsrv.n.dk/chat/gfx/items/

Comment: Check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893052/403-forbidden-access-is-denied-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-direc , Revert back, if the issue persists.