# .NET web form application redirect issue

Tags: asp.net, forms, iis-8

I have a web form app where users fill out a form, click submit and are redirected to a confirmation page.  An ID is passed through a session which then is passed to the confirmation page.  There's a intermittent issue occurring during submission, where the user is redirected to the root of the URL.  The result is a 403-Forbidden Access Denied error.  For example, user goes here: https://test.com/applications/abc.aspx?ID=25.  When they complete the form and click submit, they're redirected to https://test.com.  I do not see in my code the reason this behavior would occur.  Also, this doesn't occur for everyone.  What could cause such a behavior?  Could it be server related (IIS), network related, or application related?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Check what FRT can log about that 403 error, and you should find hints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893052/403-forbidden-access-is-denied-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-direc)

Comment: I forgot to mention that my application is on load balance servers and I'm storing the session in a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if the session data is lost during the redirection. Under certain scenarios, the below statement may result in a new session and potentially losing session data.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Account/ChangePassword.aspx");
```

Especially the scenario that the client-side requires a cookieless session.
Please refer to the official remarks of the HttpResponse.Redirect method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8